# Gstreamer tee block branch

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I want to create a pipeline that takes a rtsp stream in input and output jpeg images of different resolutions. While the pipeline is playing, I would like to block a certain branch but I don't manage to block the element.

The command line looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://ip:port/live.sdp" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=5/1 ! tee name=t ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=snapshot320-%05d.jpg t. ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=snapshot1280-%05d.jpg
```

I want to be able to block the data from passing through a branch but I can't manage to get it working with the tee element.

I've seen that the function gst_pad_add_probe allows to block a pad of an element.

This is what I did:

1) Get the pads:

```
srcpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(tee, "src");
sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(tee, "sink");
```

2) Add the probe:

```
gst_pad_add_probe(srcpad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_IDLE, &GstProbeCallback, this, NULL)
```

3) Flush the data:

```
gst_pad_send_event (sinkpad, gst_event_new_eos ());
```

4) Unref the pads

```
 gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
 gst_object_unref (srcpad);
```

5) Set the pipeline in playing state:

```
gst_element_set_state(this->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING)
```

This is the callback given to gst_pad_add_probe:

```
static GstPadProbeReturn
GstProbeCallback(GstPad* pad, GstPadProbeInfo* info, gpointer user_data) {
    std::cout << "probe callback" << std::endl;
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP;
}
```

[Update]

If I set the probe on the queue which is right after the tee element, all my branches get blocked.
More code bellow:

```
    this->pipeline = gst_pipeline_new(NULL);

if (this->pipeline == NULL) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to create the pipeline", "image_configuration");
    return NULL;
}

this->elements.tree.src = gst_element_factory_make("rtspsrc", NULL);
this->elements.tree.depay = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay", NULL);
this->elements.tree.parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", NULL);
this->elements.tree.dec = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", NULL);
this->elements.tree.rate = gst_element_factory_make("videorate", NULL);
this->elements.tree.ratefilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", NULL);
this->elements.tree.tee = gst_element_factory_make("tee", NULL);

for (auto& branch : this->elements.branches) {
    branch.queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", NULL);
    branch.scale = gst_element_factory_make("videoscale", NULL);
    branch.scalecaps = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", NULL);
    branch.enc = gst_element_factory_make("jpegenc", NULL);
    branch.sink = gst_element_factory_make("redissink", NULL);
    branch.fakesink = gst_element_factory_make("fakesink", NULL);
    if (not(branch.queue && branch.scale && branch.scalecaps && branch.sink && branch.enc &&
            branch.fakesink)) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to create elements", "image_configuration");
        return NULL;
    }
}

if (!this->pipeline || !this->elements.tree.src || !this->elements.tree.depay ||
    !this->elements.tree.parse || !this->elements.tree.dec || !this->elements.tree.rate ||
    !this->elements.tree.ratefilter || !this->elements.tree.tee) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to create elements", "image_configuration");
    return NULL;
}

this->set_rate_caps(this->elements.tree.ratefilter);
g_object_set(
    this->elements.tree.src, "location", this->loc_in.c_str(), "latency", this->latency, NULL);

for (auto& branch : this->elements.branches) {
    this->set_scale_caps(branch.scalecaps, branch.resolution);
    g_object_set(branch.enc, "quality", 50, NULL);
    g_object_set(branch.sink, "func", &send_event, NULL);
    g_object_set(branch.sink, "camera_id", this->camera_id, NULL);
    g_object_set(branch.sink, "is_init", TRUE, NULL);
}
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(this->pipeline),
                 this->elements.tree.src,
                 this->elements.tree.depay,
                 this->elements.tree.parse,
                 this->elements.tree.dec,
                 this->elements.tree.rate,
                 this->elements.tree.ratefilter,
                 this->elements.tree.tee,
                 NULL);
for (const auto& branch : this->elements.branches) {
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(this->pipeline),
                     branch.queue,
                     branch.scale,
                     branch.scalecaps,
                     branch.enc,
                     branch.sink,
                     branch.fakesink,
                     NULL);
}
if (!gst_element_link_many(this->elements.tree.depay,
                           this->elements.tree.parse,
                           this->elements.tree.dec,
                           this->elements.tree.rate,
                           this->elements.tree.ratefilter,
                           this->elements.tree.tee,
                           NULL)) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to link elements", "image_configuration");
    return NULL;
}
g_signal_connect(
    this->elements.tree.src, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), &this->elements);
for (const auto& branch : this->elements.branches) {
    if (!gst_element_link_many(this->elements.tree.tee,
                               branch.queue,
                               branch.scale,
                               branch.scalecaps,
                               branch.enc,
                               branch.sink,
                               branch.fakesink,
                               NULL)) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to link elements", "image_configuration");
        return NULL;
    }
}


if (not this->launch_pipeline()) return NULL;

getchar();
std::cout << "Add probe" << std::endl;

GstPad* srcpad;
GstPad* sinkpad;

srcpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(this->elements.branches[0].queue, "src");
sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(this->elements.branches[0].queue, "sink");
 this->elements.branches[0].probe_id =
     gst_pad_add_probe(srcpad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK, &GstProbeCallback, this, NULL);

 gst_pad_send_event (sinkpad, gst_event_new_eos ());
 gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
 gst_object_unref (srcpad);


return this->pipeline;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you saying you want to sometimes halt one portion of the branch off the tee?  If so the `valve` element could be useful.

Comment: @Luc I'm having the same problem you're describing. Did you ever find a solution?